# Upgrade from Win 7 to WIn 10 causing slowness due to home folders on DFS share

Tags: windows, directory, upgrade, dfs, folder-redirection

I have my home folders pointing to DFS share.

Problem started when I am trying to upgrade my windows 7 to Windows 10, it is trying to scan thousands of profiles on the DFS instead of the system local profiles which is taking hours for the upgrade to complete.

- Tested it with a user profile, whos home directory is not on the DFS share, the upgrade delay **does not occur**. Tested it with the Windows 1903 ISO outside of SCCM. It still occurs if the users home folder is redirected to a DFS share.
- I have tried turning off Folder redirection ​and offline files that point to the user home drive location.
- I tried placing a host file for the DFS server name in hopes the upgrade would read the host file  and stop trying to access \SFP  during the upgrade, but did not help.

I would appreciate any help on this.

Comment: You might have a look at my Q & self A on this topic here: https://serverfault.com/a/980873/216275 I was quite surprised not to have lot of community interaction until I got to the final point. This is an environment issue and the Q here (mine too) only represents one symptom of the issue. In my case too W7 clients work great.